# Multilingual HTML structure to correctly be indexed by Google

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, html

I have a page example.com that includes a language file based on visitor's country (through IP). There is only one page but several language files.

**Scenarios:**

visitor in UK or any other country not supported by my languages -> example.com (language in English)

visitor from IT -> example.com (language in Italian)

The UK visitor changes the language to Italian -> example.com/it

The IT visitor changes the language to English -> example.com/en

The IT visitor who sees tha page in English, deletes the /en from the browser -> example.com (language in Italian)

**HTML**

I have set it like

```
<html lang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="/it"  hreflang="it">
```

**Questions**

1. Should I also add the "en" version, that means all the available languages?
2. Is my structure the correct way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you load a language file like in a desktop application based on the visitors IP?

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia What I do is to identify the IP and `include(en.php)` depending on the country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is correct. For the 'all languages' version, you can use the `hreflang="x-default"` attribute for this. 
This is explained more detailed by [Googles hreflang article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en).

You could have the following elements:

```
 <html lang="en">
 <link rel="alternate" href="/it"  hreflang="it">
 <link rel="alternate" href="/"  hreflang="x-default"> <!-- or href="/en" -->
```